# How to create io.vertx.mutiny.redis.client.Response in tests

Tags: java, redis, quarkus, vert.x, mutiny

I am trying to mock out the `ReactiveRedisClient redisClient`
The signature for the get method is `io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni<io.vertx.mutiny.redis.client.Response> get(java.lang.String arg0);`

However, it doesn't seem like there is any easy way to create an `io.vertx.mutiny.redis.client.Response` directly.

I ended up with mocking it and creating this solution, but if possible, I'd like to create the Response directly and not have to mock it.

```java
Event event = new Event();
        String eventStr = event.toString();
        Response response = mock(Response.class);
        when(response.toString()).thenReturn(eventStr);
        when(redisClient.get(any())).thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().item(response));
```

Would it be possible to do the above code without mocking the Response

Docs:
https://javadoc.io/static/io.quarkus/quarkus-redis-client/1.10.1.Final/io/quarkus/redis/client/reactive/ReactiveRedisClient.html
https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny-vertx-bindings/2.8.0/apidocs/io/vertx/mutiny/redis/client/Response.html
https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/redis/client/Response.html

Answer (score 1):

`io.vertx.mutiny.redis.client.Response` wraps an object implementing the `io.vertx.redis.client.Response` interface.

So you need to mock the response and then wrap it:

```
io.vertx.redis.client.Response bareResponse = mockResponse();
io.vertx.mutiny.redis.client.Response wrapped = io.vertx.mutiny.redis.client.Response.newInstance​(bareResponse);
```